# Python - Pandas - Create a "VLOOkUP" as a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with multiple products (RaportTitle), attribute, Regions, years and a value for each. I wanna add a column that returns me the % of that value regarding the "world" (there is a row in "Regions" that is actually called "World").

[image: dataset]

I wanna add a column that takes the value of that row and divides it by the "world" value of that row's product, attribute and year... It's kind a excel "VLOOKUP".

usdaejemplo is the name of my dataframe, I tried:

```
usdaejemplo\["Porcentaje"\] = usdaejemplo.Value/(usdaejemplo\[(usdaejemplo.ReportTitle==usdaejemplo.iloc\[usdaejemplo.index\].ReportTitle)&(usdaejemplo.MarketYear==usdaejemplo.iloc\[usdaejemplo.index\].MarketYear)&(usdaejemplo.Attribute==usdaejemplo.iloc\[usdaejemplo.index\].Attribute)&(usdaejemplo.Region=="World")\].Value)
```

But returns me a NaN value

Comment: An excel Vlookup is better known in the programming world as a database "LEFT OUTER JOIN" which is a vlookup for rows in one table to get values of rows from another table based on a column they share in column. In a Pandas Dataframe context this is what the [`pandas.DataFrame.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) method. Can you share sample data for both dataframes and desired results and we can help further.

Comment: The data is in that same dataframe, but in a different row. The Region column has different countries and also the "World" entity that is the sum of every country